# Произношение слова "аллилуйя"

Tags: произношение

[Есть песня, в которой произносят слово "Аллилуйя"](https://youtu.be/yFOu_onkMVM?t=100) чуть непривычно, как будто писалось "аллэлуя". Вот такое произношение я до сих пор никогда не слышал.

Возможно, что от влияния английского языка, у русскоговорящих американцев есть свойственный говор? Или просто неправильно пишется это слово?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле по-моему есть тенденция к произнесению **Е** вместо **И**, хотя нормативное произношение соответствует написанию - [[ɐl**ʲɪ**ˈɫuɪ̯ːə]](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%8F), лично мне легче произносить именно **Е**, и нараспев мне кажется она прозносится проще, возможно это влияние русского фонетического строя...
Но в оригинале, т.е. на иврите, действительно произносится **Э**, поэтому относительно него русская орфография ошибочна. Она по всей вероятности основана на греческом произношении ἀλλ**η**λούϊα, пришедшем через старославянский.

Answer (score 6):

На ЦСЯ вариант один - Алилyїа, а ЦСЯ, при всей своей отдалённости, оказал и оказывает влияние на русский язык в области церковной и духовной лексики.

То, что звучит в песне, мне кажется однозначно иностранным произношением. До такой степени, что мне удивительно слышать следующую фразу на русском. Это похоже даже не на неправильное произношение, а на подражание американским или каким-то другим песням.